# how can post private tweet in twitter to friend/followers in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

i try to post message to friend using below code for ios

```
-(void)postMessageToFriend:(NSString *)ID withImage:(UIImage *)image{

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (granted && !error) {

            NSArray *accountsList = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            int NoOfAccounts = [accountsList count];
            if (NoOfAccounts >0) {

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/show.json"];
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsList lastObject];

                NSDictionary *p =@{@"status":@"post successfully.....",@"user_id":ID};
                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest  requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:url parameters:p];
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5);
                [postRequest addMultipartData:imageData withName:@"media[]" type:@"image/jpeg" filename:@"image.jpg"];

                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error){
                    NSError *jsonError = nil;
                    NSDictionary *friendsdata = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&jsonError];
                    NSLog(@"response value is: %@ %d ",friendsdata,[urlResposnse statusCode]);
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

here ID is friend's twitter id

while i post tweet two friend get error like below

```
errors =     (
                {
            code = 189;
            message = "Error creating status.";
        }
    );
```

please help for how can tweet to particular friend/followers in ios..

Comment: try with this url `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.format` or `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using below link i sloved my question

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a solution. Please try my below code:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

    if (granted && !error) {


        NSArray *accountsList = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        int NoOfAccounts = [accountsList count];
        if (NoOfAccounts >0) {

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json"];
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsList lastObject];


            NSDictionary *param =@{@"user_id":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userid],@"text":@"post successfully....."};
            SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:url parameters:param];
            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error){
                NSError *jsonError = nil;

                NSLog(@"response value is: %@ %d ",friendsdata,[urlResposnse statusCode]);
                               }];
        }
    }
}];
```